# Delete from pattern match until next pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed

From bash, I have a input file with various keywords and sometimes data on following lines. I would like to delete keywords starting from `PATTERN1`, until and not including lines starting with `PATTERN2`.
Note :

- there will be multiple expressions hence the `-e` option
- There may be multiple lines before the next `*`

I've tried sed such as

```
sed -i.bak -e '/*FOO/,/*/d' -e '/*BAR/,/*/d $FILE
```

but this deletes the `*KEEP` line .

```
**START
*FOO
This wants to be deleted
*KEEP
*BAR
this also wants to be deleted
*KEEP
**END
```

should become

```
**START
*KEEP
*KEEP
**END
```

Thanks in advance for looking at this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to do this using `awk`:

```
awk '/^*/{d = 0} /^*(FOO|BAR)/{d = 1} !d' file
```

```
*START
*KEEP
*KEEP
**END
```

If you're using `gnu awk` then use `-i inplace` to save changes inline:

```
awk -i inplace '/^*/{d = 0} /\*(FOO|BAR)/{d = 1} !d' file
```

If not using `gnu awk` then use:

```
awk '/^*/{d = 0} /^*(FOO|BAR)/{d = 1} !d' file > $$.tmp && mv file $$.tmp
```

Comment: Yes thank you. I did have to add ``-v RS`` to stop awk adding ``^M`` to the end of the lines

Comment: awk does not add `^M` to the end of lines. If they're in your output then its because they're in your input.

Comment: That is true. The file did originate from a windows application so the ``^M`` was already there.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^*/h;G;/^*\(FOO\|BAR\)/M!P;d' file
```

Store each key as it presents itself, in the hold space and append it to the current line. Print the first of the two lines in the pattern space if either does not contain a line beginning `*FOO` or `*BAR`.